# Error while using phc2sys for ptp slave clock sync with remote master

Tags: 16.04, ptp

I am using `Linux PTP Project`, [web site](http://linuxptp.sourceforge.net/), [source](https://github.com/openil/linuxptp), on AM3359 ICE to use ptp clock synchronization functionality.
I am able to run `ptp4l` and `phy2sys` (applications supported by Linux PTP) and getting logs for Master configuration but getting attached error when host is in slave mode and try to synchronize its clock from remote master.
[Error_log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnWKK.png)
[uname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJbpP.png)
[eth0_ethtool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Kot.png)
[eth1_ethtool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN8S9.png)

Comment: What version Ubuntu? How is this connected together?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, TI's AM335x: SDK version:  06.03.00.106, Using 3 AM3359 ICE boards connected through Ethernet ports(each board have 2 eth ports) in a ring topology.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `uname -r` and `ethtool -T eth0` (for each of the ethernet interfaces).